# VS2015 does not add newly added projects to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

If I right-click on the solution item in VS2015 Solution Explorer and select Add->Existing Project... and then add some project, the project is not added to TFS and sln file is not checked out automatically. The same situation with adding a file to a project. But if I edit a cpp file in one of the solution projects, for example, it is checked out automatically and is listed in Team Explorer/Pending Changes.

But at the same time, if I right-click on the solution item in VS2015 Solution Explorer I see "Add Solution to Source Control" item in the context menu. If I click on "Add Solution to Source Control", I get "The item 'mysoft.sln' is already under source control at the selected location." message.

When I worked with GIT, VS2015 added new files automatically to GIT ("git add newproject"), so I have an impression that something can be wrong with my VS2015/TFS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by going to File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control and binding all the projects and the solution.